# Boost asio link error

Tags: boost

Im trying to use boost asio in my project.
I downloaded boost 1.62, build it with commands:

`b2 toolset=msvc-14.0 address-model=64 architecture=x86 link=static threading=multi runtime-link=shared --build-type=minimal stage --stagedir=stage/x64 
b2 toolset=msvc-14.0 address-model=32 architecture=x86 link=static threading=multi runtime-link=shared --build-type=minimal stage --stagedir=stage/win32`

I have included my boost folded in `Additional Include Directories`, added `Additional Library Directories`, and added

```
Ws2_32.lib
Mswsock.lib
libboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_62.lib
libboost_regex-vc140-mt-gd-1_62.lib
```

to my additional dependencies list. 
But my programm with boost\asio.hpp included dont want to compile.

This are the first errors I get:

1>boost_1_62_0\boost\asio\detail\impl\socket_ops.ipp(197): error C3861: 'GetAcceptExSockaddrs': identifier not found
1>boost_1_62_0\boost\asio\detail\impl\socket_ops.ipp(217): error C2065: 'SO_UPDATE_ACCEPT_CONTEXT': undeclared identifier
1>boost_1_62_0\boost\asio\detail\impl\socket_ops.ipp(1644): error C2065: 'SO_CONNECT_TIME': undeclared identifier

I have no idea what I missed, I redownloaded and rebuilded boost several times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found out that there was some conflicts between boost asio header file and other libraries in my project (live555 library). 
So, I got rid of them by creating precompiled header file (`stdafx.h`) where boost header files were placed first, before anything else.